# React Cycling Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to make a component that displays a number of images, it will change a single image after an interval of time.

So far i have this code:

```
import React from 'react';

const Gallery = (props) => {


  const cellStyle = {
    background: "red",
    padding: "0"
  }

const ImageCell = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className="col-lg-4" style={cellStyle}>
        <div style={{
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                padding: "0",
                background: `url(${props.theImage})`,
                backgroundSize: "cover"
            }}
        >

        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

return(
  <div className="row full-width">
      {
          props.images.map(function(image) {
              let theKey = image.slice(14, -4);
              return <ImageCell key={theKey} theImage={image} />
          })
      }
  </div>
);

}

export default Gallery;
```

I want it to switch out a random image from the 6x6 grid and switch it with a random image from the image set

So i don't really know how i would implement this, any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Gallery` should hold the randomization logic and pass the images down to its children.

So, the images-to-display can be set in an array within `Gallery`'s state. Implement the `componentDidMount` method and instantiate a timer there; when the timer fires, you can replace one of the images in the state's array with a randomly selected image from the total images array. Updating state will then re-render `Gallery`, thus re-rendering its `ImageCell` children.